# Insert data into table with foreign key using Spring batch

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc, spring-batch

I have `table1` and `table2`. `table1` has a `unique key` `u1` and `table2` has a `foreign key` `fk1`

The `u1` column of `table1` is an `Auto Increment` column. So it's unique all the item.

Now if I this using JDBC

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(name, status) values(?,?)
```

Let's say I got the following values in `u1`, `name`, status columns inserted `1`, `john`, `pass`

I need to some how get the value of the `u1` which is `1` into my `foreign key` `fk2` in `table2` before I start inserting records into `table2`. So my `table2` records will look like `fk2`, `company`, `sub_status` ----> `1`, `abc corp`, `live`

I'm using `Spring Batch` `Java` to write data into `MySql` database.

Comment: Do you need pure jdbc? Or can you use Hibernate?

Comment: @DeanClark : I'm using `Spring Batch`. I googled and found that I need to get the `ID` of the last `insert` using `getGeneratedKeys` method. But every one is saying that it's not possible to get the `getGeneratedKeys` in `Spring Batch`